# IR incandescent lamp modeling in ltspice

Tags: ltspice

This is my first post here,
I’m new to electronics and am trying to model the IR source to make a suitable driver circuit for it.
so, how to build a ltspice model to match the specifications shown in the image (datasheet)?
Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Try searching for a SPICE model for a filament light bulb, maybe adapt it. Otherwise it looks like a simple slope fit, which could as well be a resistor.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thank you for your help and fast reply

Comment: Don't know if it matters, but the *hot* resistance of tungsten-filament radiators may be an order of magnitude higher than *cold* resistance. There is a large initial inrush current, in most cases.

Comment: you are right, and this complicates the driver circuit for the lamp